# How to unit test a bot in JavaScript that can receive attachments from users?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework

I am doing unit test for my bot written in node.js based on the Microsoft document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/unit-test-bots?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript.

In the test, I can create a client object and make the client send text to the bot like

```
const reply = await client.sendActivity('hi!');
assert.strictEqual(reply, expected_reply);
```

But my bot was designed to also be able to receive attachment from users, how can I make the client send an attachment to the bot?

Comment: is your issue resolved? are you having issues with sending an attachment to the bot ? what have you tried so far?